# Rails send_file rendering files as plain text on new page instead of browser downloading file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sendfile

When send_file is called, it's sending the file to the browser, but the browser is dumping the contents as plain-text on a new page instead of downloading the file. If I refresh that page, it then downloads the file as normal.

**Route**

```
get 'download' => 'qr_codes#download'
```

**Controller**

```
def download
    path = Rails.root.join("events/active/#{params[:name]}/#{params[:batch]}/#{params[:file]}")
    send_file(path, type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel', filename: params[:file])
end
```

**View**

```
<%= link_to 'Original Upload', download_path(name: @event_name,
  batch: batch, file: batch_upload_filename(@event_name, batch)) %>
```

**SOLUTION:**
This ended up being a [known issue](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-classic/issues/182) with turbolinks. If using Turbolinks 5 like I am, the updated syntax is: `data: { turbolinks: false }`

Answer (score 3):

This ended up being a known issue with turbolinks. If using Turbolinks 5 like I am, the updated syntax is:

```
data: { turbolinks: false }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the disposition:

```
def download
  path = Rails.root.join("events/active/#{params[:name]}/#{params[:batch]}/#{params[:file]}")
  send_file(path, type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel', filename: params[:file], disposition: 'attachment')
end
```

Or changing the file to ensure the extension is correct

```
"#{params[:file][0,params[:file].index(".")]}.xlsx"
```

Oh and don't inject params into a string to build routes for downloading.  I can inject "../../" into :name, "config", into :batch, and "../config/database.yml" into :file.  Add the file path to a model.

Comment: The disposition is defaulted to 'attachment'. I tried setting it anyways and encountered the same result. I also ensured the file extension was correct per your suggestion and got the same result.

Comment: If I go here directly it downloads fine `"http://localhost:3000/download?batch=1&file=HSS.xls&name=HSS+2016"`, only when I link to this path from a different page does it render the plain-text in the browser, then as I mentioned in post, refreshing the plaintext page, will then download the file as normal.

Answer (score 0):

make helper method

```
def some_helper(content_type)
 Rack::Mime::MIME_TYPES.invert[content_type].gsub(/\./mi, '')
end
```

and update link as

```
<%= link_to 'Original Upload', download_path(name: @event_name, batch: batch, file: batch_upload_filename(@event_name, batch, format: file_format(attachment.file.content_type))) %>
```